# Does the "Sono" system for noise canceling on a window work?

Tags: technology, sound

“Sono” is supposed to turn your window into an advanced noise canceling system 
that allows you to eliminate and/оr control the sounds that pass through:

Gajitz [writes](http://gajitz.com/high-tech-window-cling-is-like-a-volume-knob-for-real-life/):

> Created by industrial designer Rudolf Stefanich, the Sono sticks to glass surfaces and literally allows you to dial down unwanted noise. After it receives a sound’s vibrations, it reprocesses them much like the active noise cancellation technology used in certain headphones. Sono’s interface acts as a dial, letting you choose which sounds you want blocked from your fortress of solitude.

Does this work?

Comment: The _theory_ certainly seems solid. However, the page you linked to states that it is "[c]urrently just a working prototype" (and doesn't give any clue as to how well it's "working" or how close to production), so I'm not sure if this counts as a notable claim.

Comment: Similar techniques are used in cars to reduce road, wind and engine noise. There is no reason why not the same principles could be used elsewhere.

Comment: As said before the theory behind it is already widely employed in active noise canceling systems from mid-tier headphones to cars to construction sites; I cant see why the same ideas cant apply to windows.